# sequential execution of Jquery Defers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

In the below code, I want sequential executuon of the method saveBulkUploadSinglePacket in the while loop, that means process next packet after completion of the current packet. How to achieve that.

```
var saveBulkUploadSinglePacket = function(){
while (packetCount<=bulkUploadPackets.length){
            $.when(saveBulkUploadSinglePacket(modelToSave)).done(function(arguments){
                saveBulkUploadPackets.push(arguments);
                packetCount++;
            });

        }
  return saveBulkUploadPackets;

}



var saveBulkUploadSinglePacket = function(modelToSave){
        var defer = $.Deferred();
        $.when(new SaveBulkUpload().save(modelToSave)).done(function(arguments){
            defer.resolve(arguments);
        }).fail(function(errorObj){  
           defer.reject(errorObj);
        });

        return defer.promise();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to say "perform x when promise is done" is through `promise.then()`. Keep track of the current promise in a var outside the loop and attach each call to the previous promise with a `.then()`:

```js
var saveBulkUploadSinglePacket = function(){
    var lastPromise = $.when();
    while (packetCount<=bulkUploadPackets.length){
        lastPromise = (
           lastPromise
             .then(function(){
                 // make sure saveBulkUploadSinglePacket returns a promise
                 return saveBulkUploadSinglePacket(modelToSave));
             })
             .then(function(){
                 saveBulkUploadPackets.push(arguments);
                 packetCount++;
                 // return a resolved promise
                 return $.when();
             })
        );
    }
    lastPromise.resolve(saveBulkUploadPackets);
    return lastPromise;
}
```

At the end of the function I resolved the final promise with the desired return value, then returned the promise. This way you can call `saveBulUploadSinglePacket().then(...)` to wait for all the promises to complete and handle the result.

Comment: it's complaining lastPromise.resolve is not a function.

Comment: forgot to save the sequential promises in the `lastPromise` var; try the updated code

Comment: I am facing the same issue, can you please help

Comment: Looking over this again, I think the issue is probably that your functions being passed to `.then()` (`saveBulkUploadSinglePacket()` and the anonymous function around `saveBulUploadPackets()`) aren't returning promises, so the `.then()`s aren't chaining properly. I updated the code in the second function to manually create and return a promise, but you need to make sure that `saveBulkUploadSinglePacket()` returns a promise when it's complete as well

Comment: var saveBulkUploadSinglePacket = function(modelToSave){
  var defer = $.Deferred();
  $.when(new SaveBulkUpload().save(modelToSave)).done(function(){
   defer.resolve(arguments);
  }).fail(function(errorObj){  
     defer.reject(errorObj);
  });
  
  return defer.promise();
  
 }

Comment: above is the function, it is returning a promise(), I believe.

Comment: `$.when()` isn't meant to take an asynchronous function and turn it into a promise-based function, it's meant to work with synchronous functions. So I have two questions about `SaveBulkUpload.save()`: first, is it asynchronous? For example, is it using AJAX to send data to a server? If it's *not* asynchronous, then the problem is elsewhere. If it *is*, second question: does it return a promise? if not, `$.when()` won't do you any good; it won't wait for `save()` to be done. If so, this function is unecessary. Just call `(new SaveBulkUpload().save(modelToSave))` directly from the `while` loop.

Comment: SaveBulkUpload.save() is an AJAX post call and it is using Defers and returning Defer.promise()

Comment: if it's actually returning a promise, then there's really nothing more I can tell you without sitting in front of the whole codebase and poking around. If you're still getting an error that `lastPromise.resolve()` is not a function, and you're sure that your code matches what I have above, I'd try `console.log(lastPromise)` right before that line to make sure you're really getting what you think you're getting. Try sprinkling console logs throughout your function; you may find some surprises

Comment: Actually , now I discovered I have a different problem. your solution is working, but the problem is, I want first defer to complete before I second one runs and so on. They run in order and only after previous one completes.

Comment: I have raised different question, you may want to have a look.                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36626803/array-to-ajax-call-call-next-only-after-previous-complete

Answer (score 0):

To save your pakets sequentially, use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to build a `.then()` chain very concisely, as follows :

```
var saveBulkUploadPackets = function(packets) {
    return packets.reduce(function(promise, paket) {
        return promise.then(function(results) {
            return (new SaveBulkUpload()).save(paket).then(function(res) {
                return results.concat(res);
            });
        });
    }, $.when([]));
}
```

And call like this :

```
saveBulkUploadPackets(bulkUploadPackets).then(function(results) {
    // All done.
    // use/log the `results` array here.
});
```