# AJAX call in array loop, call next only after previous complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have an array to upload data and I want them to send to server one by one.
I want the previous one to complete before I send next one.
Actually, after each response I want to decide whether to send next one or not.

```
while (packetCount < bulkUploadPackets.length) {
  d = d.then(save(bulkUploadPackets[packetCount]))
    .then(function(uploadResponse) {
      //I want to come here after first call complete 
      //before second call is fired and so on
      packetCount++;
    });
}


save: function(modelToSave) {
  var defer = $.Deferred();
  var self = this;
  this.model = modelToSave;
  Backbone.sync('create', this, {
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log("success" + data);
      defer.resolve(data);
    },
    error: function(response) {
      defer.reject(errorObj);
    }
  });

  return defer.promise();
}
```

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, and you should use it asynchronously. If you want to maintain some processing order, you shouldn't fight with AJAX to do so, but rather implement that logic server-side and send the whole array in one request...

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive function and put recursive call inside then:

```
(function loop() {
     if (packetCount<bulkUploadPackets.length) {
           d = d.then(save(bulkUploadPackets[packetCount]))
                .then(function(uploadResponse){
                      //I want to come here after first call complete before second call is fired and so on
                      packetCount++;
                      loop();
                 }); 
     }
})();
```

Comment: but how would it ensure, it fires next before completing previous one

Comment: It will execute the function when promise is resolved. second call to loop will always be executed when first promise is resolved.